# Sanitize user input for DB stored procedure calls / query builder / eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel and my DB calls are as follows.

At some places, I am using Eloquent

```
$model = new UserModel(Input::all())
$model->save();
```

At some places, I am using query builder

```
$users = DB::table('Users')->where('ID', $id)->get();
```

At some places, I am using stored procedures

```
DB::statement('CALL usp_AddUser("' . $iName . '","' . $iDomain . '","' . $iAlias . '",@oMessage)');
```

Does laravel sanitize user input for the above 3 scenarios?. Would it sufficient to simply escape the user input using **htmlspecialchars()**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DB::statement` call is unsafe (assuming `$iName` etc. come from user/unsafe input - it'd be *relatively* safe if those values came from your code only and you were careful with them). The other two are fine.

`htmlspecialchars` does not escape for SQL, it escapes for HTML, a totally separate set of rules.

`DB::statement` will allow for use of PDO placeholders, which ensures safety:

```
DB::statement('CALL usp_AddUser(:iName, :iDomain, :iAlias, @oMessage)', ['iName' => $iName, 'iDomain' => $iDomain, 'iAlias' => $iAlias]);
```

or

```
DB::statement('CALL usp_AddUser(?, ?, ?, @oMessage)', [$iName, $iDomain, $iAlias]);
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Yes, these values come from user input (for all scenarios). For the DB::statement, I will change it as per your inputs.